# If EditText.getText().ToString() == "" dont work;

Tags: android, android-edittext

Here is my code:

```
if(editText.getText().toString() == ""){
   editTextBenefaction.setText("0");
}
```

Why he didn't work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change it to

```
if(editText.getText().toString().equals("")){
```

In Java `.equals()` is used to compare if they have the same value and "==" is used to determine if they reference the same object.

An even better way is to use

```
if("".equals(editText.getText().toString())){
```

because this will protect against a `NPE`.

[Java String Docs](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.oracle.com%2Fjavase%2Ftutorial%2Fjava%2Fdata%2Fcomparestrings.html&ei=chRgUtXBK6mfyQGn-4GQAg&usg=AFQjCNF3Z_YhX4OrkuIOLJ0fEULdanZSLA&sig2=-ch2lTKsqq9amLcGcnPjfg&bvm=bv.54176721,d.aWc)

Comment: Thanks, but Eclipse show that second variation have error.

Comment: Yes, see my edit. I didn't clean up the "()"

Answer (score 2):

**Do not** use == with Strings use equals()

```
if(editText.getText().toString().equals("")){
   editTextBenefaction.setText("0");
}
```