# set visibility of a button if edittext is not empty

Tags: java, android

I have a submit button where I need to set the visibility of the button based on if a edittext field is empty or not.

I have below snippet in the **onCreate** method of the activity

```
submitIssue.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

if(issueTxt.getText().toString() == ""){
    submitIssue.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}else{
    submitIssue.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

On launching the application the button displays even though the edittext is empty. What is wrong with my approach?

Comment: Try `issueTxt.getText().toString().isEmpty()` initially

Comment: Please what has this question done to get downvote. does everyone not learn on their own pace

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19432553/if-edittext-gettext-tostring-dont-work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use like this

```
 editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                   if (s.toString().length()<1){
                      button.setVisibility(View.GONE)
                   }else button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this-:

```
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(issueTxt.getText().toString()))
{
   submitIssue.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
else
{
   submitIssue.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Android provides `TextUtils.isEmpty()` utility method:

```
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(issueTxt.getText().toString())){
    submitIssue.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
} else {
    submitIssue.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
   if(editText.getText().toString().trim().equals("")){

}
```

Or

```
if(editText.getText().toString().trim().length==0){
}
```

Always try to use trim() function when checking edittext is empty or not because if you use without trim() function than space(" ") can create issue for you...

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
               // Add your code here
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
```

you can use TextChangeLister for other process.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use **TextWatcher()** for achieve this.

and For Matching string you should use `equals()` method  instead od `==`

eg :

```
String1.equals(String2)
```

Refer the Below Links:

[TexWatcher fo Android](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html)

[TextChangerListener Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20824634/android-on-text-change-listener)

You can use TextWatcher for your edittext,

eg:

```
 editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                   if(TextUtils.isEmpty(issueTxt.getText().toString()))
                   {
                        submitIssue.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                   }
                   else
                   {
                        submitIssue.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                   } 

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // You can do Validation here too
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
submitIssue.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    if(issueTxt.getText().toString().length() == 0){
        submitIssue.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }else{
        submitIssue.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```